# SharePoint 2010 - Site Template with Folders

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, folder

I have ran into an issue where a user has wanted to create a site template of a site that contains folders in a 'Shared Documents' web part.

When we create the site template and include the content and then try to use that site template to create a new site it fails miserably.  If we were to create another site template while not including the content, it works like a charm.

Why does it fail if I include the content?

I have found the following errors in the logs:

*Failed to activate site-scoped features for template 'STS#1' in site "http://site"*

*Failed to activate web features when provisioning site at url "http://site" with site definition "STS#1".*

*Failed to apply template "STS#1" to web at URL "http://site"*

*Failed to apply template "STS#1" to web at URL "http://site", error Adding properties to the folder with url Shared Documents/3.Design failed while activating feature, the folder does not exist. 0x203cb7d0*

Comment: Can you please post up your custom configurations of you onet.xml

Comment: I found that some folders were _corrupt_?  They were throwing errors in the SharePoint logs.  So we deleted them and recreated them.  Now it is just taking the folder names (i.e. 1.Testing, 2.Planning, etc..) and renaming them to 1, 2, 3, and so on.